# Find path to the node using ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Wih [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), I can print every occurences of a specific tag (in my case `ExpertSettingsSg`
):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('mydoc.xml').getroot()

for children in root:
    value=children.findall('.//ExpertSettingsSg')#tag I'm looking for
    for settings in value:
        if settings.text is not None:
            print(settings.text)
```

But I didn't find a way to print the path of the occurence. Because my XML file has many levels and because `ExpertSettingsSg` can be almost at every level, I need to know where the `ExpertSettingsSg` come from. I'm looking for something like

> Path to config xxxxxx = /root/xxx/aaaa/bbbb

If it's not possible with [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), does any other library do the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the nodes, you can walk the tree and collect paths (borrowing the example from @valdi-bo):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

txt ='''<main>
  <x>
    <a>
      <ExpertSettingsSg id="1">x1</ExpertSettingsSg>
    </a>
    <b>
      <dummy>xxxx</dummy>
    </b>
  </x>
  <y>
    <c>
      <dummy>xxxx</dummy>
    </c>
    <d>
      <ExpertSettingsSg id="2">x2</ExpertSettingsSg>
    </d>
    <e>
      <ExpertSettingsSg id="3"/>
    </e>
  </y>
</main>'''


def node_walk(root: ET.Element):
    path_to_node = []
    node_stack = [root]
    while node_stack:
        node = node_stack[-1]
        if path_to_node and node is path_to_node[-1]:
            path_to_node.pop()
            node_stack.pop()
            yield (path_to_node, node)
        else:
            path_to_node.append(node)
            for child in reversed(node):
                node_stack.append(child)


root = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(txt))

for node in root.findall('.//ExpertSettingsSg'):
    for node_path, n in node_walk(root.getroot()):
        if n is node:
            xpath = "/".join(["."] + [n.tag for n in node_path[1:]] + [n.tag])
            print(xpath, node)
            # NOTE: Assert is to just show that the xpath is correct.
            assert root.getroot().find(xpath) == node
```

You would get output like this:

```
./x/a/ExpertSettingsSg <Element 'ExpertSettingsSg' at 0x102cf5b80>
./y/d/ExpertSettingsSg <Element 'ExpertSettingsSg' at 0x102cf5db0>
./y/e/ExpertSettingsSg <Element 'ExpertSettingsSg' at 0x102cf5e50>
```

Instead of walking multiple times, we can walk once and collect all relevant nodes with path, like this:

```
xpaths = []
for node_path, n in node_walk(root.getroot()):
    if n.tag == "ExpertSettingsSg":
        xpath = "/".join(["."] + [n.tag for n in node_path[1:]] + [n.tag])
        xpaths.append(xpath)

for xpath in xpaths: 
    node = root.getroot().find(xpath)
    print(xpath, node)
```